# Formulário Yup com erro react native

Tags: react-native, axios, yup, formik

Estou tentando cadastrar alguns usuários em meu banco de dados, mais meu YUP não está chamando a função handleRegister para cadastrar, porém quando eu executo a função handlerRegister sem a utilização do yup é realizado o cadastro com sucesso

se eu passar a função dessa forma `onPress={handleRegister}` o cadastro é concluido.

mais seu eu passar o handleRegister dentro da função handleSubmit não acontece nada

esse é meu código completo

YUP

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required("Nome é obrigatório"),
  email: Yup.string().email("Email inválido").required("Email requerido"),
  cpf: Yup.string().required(""),
});
```

```
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });
```

chamada na api

```
 async function handleRegister() {
    await api
      .post("/users", {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        type: type,
      })
      .then(() => {
        navigate("Confirmation", {
          title: "Conta criada!",
          message: "",
          nextScreenRoute: "SignIn",
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        Alert.alert("Opa!", "Não foi possível cadastrar" + err);
      });

  }
```

Botao

```
onPress={handleSubmit(handleRegister)}
```

Fiz um console log no handleRegister ele retorna

```
[Function _callee3]
```

Eu imagino que seja algum erro na montagem do POST mais até agora não consigo soluncionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo por que a sua função `handleSubmit` é assíncrona.

Tente ajustar o seu código para:

```js
onPress={async () => await handleSubmit(handleRegister)}
```